# PHP - Microtime

Tags: php, microtime

How php microtime generated, why only 13 - 15 numbers returned and if i write time manually like this:

```
<?php
$time = date('SAMPLE').date('SAMPLE').date('SAMPLE').date('SAMPLE').date('SAMPLE');
$TIME = microtime(true);
?>
```

and microtime look too short for contains all of date (Year,Month,Date,Hour,Minute,second)
Is microtime really unique ?

Please give your opinion ...

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain yourself better. What are you trying to achieve, and what exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds. This function is only available on operating systems that support the gettimeofday() system call.

If you want to convert the timestamp into a human-readable date look at the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: but is microtime unique ?

Comment: for each microsecond your computer experiences, it is.

Comment: @MichaelAntonius `uniqid()` is unique